# JOLT - filtering array based on object value

Tags: jolt

how can I do this?
This is the array....
Can you please help me?

Can you please give me the answer???? Thanks a lot

```
{
  "results": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "xx",           
        "typeRelationship": [
          {
            "relationship": "parent",
            "type": {                
              "id": "yyyyy",                 
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "xxxxxxxx"
      },
      {
        "name": "yy",         
        "typeRelationship": [
          {
            "relationshipType": "parent",
            "type": {
              "id": "CCCC"
            }
          },
          {
            "relationshipType": "child",
            "service": {
              "id": "DDDD"
            }
          },
          {
            "relationshipType": "child",
            "service": {
              "id": "xxxxxxxx"
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "yyyyy"
      }
    ]
  }}
```

expected:
This is expected:

```
{
  "data" : [ {
    "id" : "xxxx",
    "href" : "xxxxxx",
    "relation":"parent"
  } ]
}
```

For some reason I need to type so it does let me update!!!

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "id": {
              "xxxx": {
                "@3": "data[]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit 1**

The below spec moves all the values which as id=xxxxx to the data array.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "*": {
              "id": {
                "xxxx": {
                  "@(2)": "data[]",
                  "@(4,relation)": "data[&3].relation"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This totally works.
Thanks.
Can you please let me know what is 2? 3? 4?
Because my array is a bit different and I want to fix those numbers but does not work....

```
{
  "results": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "xx",           
        "typeRelationship": [
          {
            "relationship": "parent",
            "type": {                
              "id": "yyyyy",                 
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "xxxxxxxx"
      },
      {
        "name": "yy",         
        "typeRelationship": [
          {
            "relationshipType": "parent",
            "type": {
              "id": "CCCC"
            }
          },
          {
            "relationshipType": "child",
            "service": {
              "id": "DDDD"
            }
          },
          {
            "relationshipType": "child",
            "service": {
              "id": "xxxxxxxx"
            }
          }
        ],
        "id": "yyyyy"
      }
    ]
  }
```

}

expected:

```
{
  "rows" : [  {
    "rowdata" : {
      "relationshipType" : "child",
      "Name" : "yy",
      "id" : "yyyyy"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Those numbers are counts of shifts, and the wildcard (@,$ ect) determines the action or direction of the shift.

Comment: Also, update the findings, by editing your original post or place comments. Don't add it to the answer section.
So, this post will be helpful for the other users also.